# Do .NET DLL's not export anything

Tags: .net, dll

I recently created a DLL libray in F#. I have never created a DLL for the .NET Framework, but I have programmed a couple in pure Win32 C++. Typically, when I wrote a C++ DLL, I used a utility like [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html), to see that my functions were correctly exported. Normally, It worked, but when I reviewed my DLL I made in F#, it showed no exported functions. Is this an issue with my build?, or do .NET DLL's just not explicitly export anything?

btw this is my build output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\Release\n00b_lib.dll --debug:pdbonly --noframework --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Release\n00b_lib.XML --optimize+ -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\..\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETCore\3.3.1.0\FSharp.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\mscorlib.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Collections.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ComponentModel.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Globalization.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.IO.Compression.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.IO.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Linq.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Net.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Net.Http.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Net.Primitives.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Net.Requests.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Numerics.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ObjectModel.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Reflection.Context.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Reflection.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Security.Principal.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ServiceModel.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Text.Encoding.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Threading.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Windows.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Xml.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Xml.Linq.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Xml.Serialization.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" --target:library --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --validate-type-providers --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --highentropyva- --sqmsessionguid:40b01f12-73d1-4165-a5a5-0d55fc3a0d0d --targetprofile:netcore "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7.AssemblyAttributes.fs" n00b_lib.fs 
    n00b_lib -> C:\Users\James\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\n00b_lib\n00b_lib\bin\Release\n00b_lib.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Yes, .NET DLLs do not export functions like C++. However you can use a tool like ILSpy or .NET Reflector to see the contents of the assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the right tools like the ones mentioned in @Ryan's comment.

Like C++ DLL exports table, a .NET DLL exposes its "functions and classes (and other information)" via [a set of tables in CLR metadata](http://iobservable.net/blog/2013/05/12/introduction-to-clr-metadata/).

> The CLR metadata is organized as a normalized relational database. This means that CLR metadata consists of rectangular tables with foreign keys between each other. In case you have previous experience with databases you should be familiar with this concept. Since .NET 2.0 there are more than 40 tables that define the CLR metadata. Here is a sample list of some of the tables:
>
> Module (0x00) – contains information about the current module
>
> TypeRef (0x01) – contains information about the types that are referenced from other modules
>
> TypeDef (0x02) – contains information about the types defined in the current module
>
> Field (0x04) – contains information about the fields defined in the current module
>
> Method (0x06) – contains information about the methods defined in the current module
>
> Property (0x17) – contains information about the properties defined in the current module
>
> Assembly (0x20) – contains information about the current assembly
> AssemblyRef (0x23) – contains information about the referenced assemblies

Note that not only the "exported" (public types and methods) are visible, types and methods that are internal or private are also visible.

Below is a screenshot of ILDASM.exe, which is part of the .NET Framework SDK.

[image]